# sshd connections unexpectedly close on windows 2012

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012

I have been using FreeSSHD to connect to my Windows servers[Windows 2K3 -R2 Enterprise servers and Windows 2K8-R2 Enterprise servers]. The Windows command prompt shows up after a successful SSH connection (i.e Windows platform).

[My Observations]:
In case of Windows server 2012, the FreeSSHD installation goes through fine. I am able to make an SSH connection to the server from a remote machine. However, the SSH connection unexpectedly close and the putty terminal closes immediately. I enabled FreeSSHD logging and noticed that the connection is successfully made but terminated immediately.

The putty log shows the following error message:

tester@server-w12-1's password: 
Could not create child desktop: Access is denied.

I tried installing CopSSH. With this I am able to establish stable SSH connections. But it uses cygwin platform. I referred to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers" to get the list of available SSH servers.

[Rephrased Question]:
In my application I am using SSH calls to connect to server (Windows & Linux) to query drive specific details. Can someone please suggest a free SSH server that runs on Windows 2012 server or suggest a fix for FreeSSHD session disconnect issue?

EDIT : 
I was unable to add an answer or add a long comment. So I am posting an edit.

[Solution]

Thanks Travis for your guidence. The issue is resolved. I did the following:

1. Disable the setting "User Account Control: run all Administrators in admin approval mode" under local security policy
2. Right Click FreeSSHd icon and click "Run as Administrator"
3. Select the option "Run as Administrator" under "Compatibility" tab of FreeSSHd application properties
4. As Travis had mentioned, ensure the SSH server is running. If not change the port# under FreeSSHd's SSH tab  to say 222 and get it running. Restart the service
5. My program needs the default port 22. So I changed the port back to 22 and I was able to have the service running
6. I was able to SSH to the server even after multiple restarts

Comment: Have you checked if SSH server is up and running in your FreeSSHd Settings Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check following steps

1.) FreeSSHd is running as a service.

2.) SSH Service is running on the FreeSSHd console . [image: It should be like this]

3.) If it not starting try changing the port of SSH under the SSH tab(for example 430 in my case).[image: Like this]

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!FreeSSHd is running as a service. The SSH service is not running on the FreeSSHd console. I am assuming you are talking about the screen where FreeSSHd notifies the user if Telnet and SSH services are running(with a green check sign). Please correct me if I am wrong. Even though it is not running I have managed to have SSH work successfully with W2k3 and W2k8 servers. Please let me know if you managed to connect to Windows server 2012 using FreeSSHd?

Comment: Yes .. please start the SSH service. Until you start the service, you wont be able to connect via SSH

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot. That is what I was talking about as well. I have been able to connect to windows server using SSH even when the server status was "SSH server is not running". I change the settings in the "Authentication" tab [Password Authentication - "Required" and Public Key Authentication - "Disabled" ]

Comment: it could be that some other SSH server is running on that port. You can try to change the Port on FreeSSHd to something like `5000` and see if you can still connect using port `5000`. Also you can Add Users in the `users` tab.

Comment: A friend of mine told me that he had the same issue. He connected another interface in Eth1. He used that IP for the Listen address. My Windows2012 server is currently running some powerfail tests. I will test the port settings you suggested and let you know. Can you please tell me if you were able to successfully connect with these settings ?

Comment: yes i was. I even tried from win 7 and XP and was able to connect.

Comment: I tried changing the port# and I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: I reckon you have installed a one too many SSHd clients. what i would recommend now is to uninstall all and do a fresh install of one of them . While runnning FreeSSHd ensure you Console as`run as administrator. and before you use putty, ensure the SSH service is running.

Comment: With FreeSSHd I am able to successfully connect to the Windows Server 2012 using telnet. Only SSH seems to have issues. FYI, I have ensured that SSH service is running and I am running as an administrator

Comment: Great. If my solution has helped you then a upvote would be great :)

Comment: I don't seem to have privileges to do anything...I have marked this as an answer. Hope that gives you points!Thanks again...